# Understanding plotted ACF on stationary time-series data

Tags: time-series, pandas, statsmodels, pacf

I made time-series data stationary and plotter ACF & PCF, while PCF looks fine, I do not know how to interpretate ACF, as it looks like this - I could not say it geometrical. For PACF - it is Significant till 1 lag
[image]